# does size of argument in a javascript function affects its performance?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, subset

I have a key value pair containing five keys with values as huge array of thousand objects each . I can either subset it while passing it into a function or i can pass whole array in the function.

For e.g:

```
keyVal ={"first_array": Object[1000],
"second_array": Object[1000],
"third_array": Object[1000],
"fourth_array": Object[1000]
}
var first_arr = keyVal.first_array
```

Two possibilities:

```
function notSubsettedArgs(keyVal){
$.each(keyVal.first_array,function(i,item){
//some processing});
}

function subsettedArgs(first_array){
$.each(first_array,function(i,item){
//do some processing});
}
```

Does it make difference in javascript ?
Does function takes the load of size of arguments ?
Thanks

Comment: did you try testing it?

Comment: since it appears that the data will live before and after the function call in question, it likely makes no difference, you're passing "pointers" either way.

Comment: Use [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/) to run comparitive tests.

Comment: @dandavis  is it like passing argument as pointers ?

Comment: yes, it's like that. don't get too specific with semantics, or we'll be here all day, but when you pass an object in js, you essentially pass a ref to the object. if the processing isn't preventing garbage collection, the cpu/ram usage should be constant.

Comment: It's possible that the only performance hit you might get is using jQuery's `each` instead of JS native functions. I've not tested this tho, so take it with a pinch of salt.

Comment: @Andy: in both cases, $.each() is passed the exact same thing...

Comment: @DLeh what tool to use ?

Comment: any web browser. write some test code.

Comment: @DLeh i meant for benchmarking, how do i do that ?

Comment: performance is measured it time, so start a timer before you call a function with a big parameter, compared to a small parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript passes arrays and objects to functions by passing a copy of the reference to the array/object, so it is likely to be fine to pass the whole thing. Just know that if you mutate it in the function, those changes will affect your original array/object!

If this is browser code and not server (e.g., Node.js) code, you can test with [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/). Just be careful. [It's easy to do JS benchmarks wrong!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65-RbBwZQdU)

Comment: *"JavaScript passes arrays and objects to functions by reference"* To be more precise, JavaScript passes everything by *value*, but the value is a reference to an object. That's different from the actual meaning of *pass by reference*.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to make the language more precise: "JavaScript passes arrays and objects to functions by passing a copy of the reference to the array/object"